# php - imagemagick obscure image with black

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want to shade the original image with black color with some opacity. Want to make the original image a little bit darker. I use write this code, but it's does not work:

```
$image = new Imagick("test.jpg");

$drawblacklayer = new ImagickDraw();
$drawblacklayer->setFillColor('black');
$drawblacklayer->setFillOpacity(0.8);
$coordinate = array( array( 'x' => 0, 'y' => 0 ), array( 'x' => 200, 'y' => 200 ) ); // seems need to use the original size of $image, but it's testing

$drawblacklayer->polygon($coordinate);

$image->drawImage($drawblacklayer);

header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Comment: What does not work ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I expect to see the darkened square in the picture, but output is the original picture without changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expecting a darkened square, your `$coordinate` array will need to have all points defined.

```php
$coordinate = array( 
    array( 'x' =>   0, 'y' =>   0 ), // Top-Left
    array( 'x' => 200, 'y' =>   0 ), // Top-Right
    array( 'x' => 200, 'y' => 200 ), // Bottom-Right
    array( 'x' =>   0, 'y' => 200 ), // Bottom-Left

);
$drawblacklayer->polygon($coordinate);
```

Or use the [ImagickDraw::rectangle](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.rectangle.php) method.

```
$drawblacklayer->rectangle( 0, 0, 200, 200 );
```